# Keep rows of thumbnail previews evenly distributed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery as the core foundations of a web admin back-end. I have added a "Media Uploader" that opens in a BS Modal, which is working fine, however as the images are uploaded (one-by-one using `dropzone.js`) they get added to the main preview area, prepended to the existing images.

When this happens, if the images aren't all the same height, I get the following result:

[image: Misaligned image thumbnails]

I know what the cause is, I just want to know if there's a simple approach to fixing this issue. Here is the markup the makes each thumbnail box:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 media-col">
    <div class="box media-box">
        <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <img src="SOME IMAGE">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" value="SOME IMAGE URL">
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

All images are inside of a single `<div class="row"></div>`

My main issue is the responsiveness of the image thumbnails. I can't create a wrapper for every X # of images as the amount of images displayed per line changes based on the screen resolution.

Comment: If you have the possibility to do so, you can put a `clear: left` on the element that falls into the second row. That'll clear it of predecessor siblings that might cause layout issues. Of course this is hard to do when your layout is responsive and you don't know which element will start a new row. I'd just go and try out if `display: table` and `display: table-cell` instead of Bootstrap's grid stuff will cut it. You then of course will miss out on all the responsive stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the bizarre effect of how floats work in CSS. It makes sense if you understand it but can seem very strange if you don't.

I'd recommend setting the main blocks to `display:inline-block` rather than `float:left`. Then they will automatically 'row' themselves, regardless of screen width, like so:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/zxXOWX

The other option would be to use something like masonry, which will `absolute`ly (and robustly) position all the elements in a nice way.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: That sort of worked. On really short images it still broke. What I ended up doing was using an Unordered List instead. I set the height of the images to a 130px and added `overflow:hidden` to the image containers. This gives a uniform look across the whole row. I could've done something similar with my last method, but `<ul></ul>` was simpler. Thanks very much for your answer, though.